# JBoss as a windows service. Where can i set the JAVA_OPTS?

Tags: memory, windows-services, jboss

I'm running JBoss as a windows service, but i can't seem to find where i can configure the JAVA_OPTS to make it work properly.
I need to set the Xms and the Xmx.

I have tried to just run JBoss manually (run.bat) and in the same file i set the JAVA_OPTS= -Xms128m -Xmx512m. And that works.

Here is my install.bat where i install the JBoss as a service:

```
set JBOSS_CLASS_PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\run.jar

rem copy /Y JavaService.exe D:\PROJECT\bin\JBossService.exe

JBossService.exe -install JBoss %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll -Djava.class.path=%JBOSS_CLASS_PATH% -start org.jboss.Main -stop org.jboss.Shutdown -method systemExit -out %PROJECT_HOME%\log\JBoss_out.log -err %PROJECT_HOME%\log\JBoss_err.log -current D:\PROJECT\bin
net start JBoss
```

When i look at the info about JBoss Application Server (http://localhost:8080/web-console/) i see this info:

```
JVM Environment
Free Memory: 9 MB
Max Memory: 63 MB
Total Memory: 63 MB
```

And i MUST have more Max Memory.

Does anybody know where i can set the JAVA_OPTS when running JBoss as a service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use jbosssvc.exe to run JBoss as a service.  It basically runs your run.bat, so you can include all the customizations you want.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossNativeWindows

In the bin directory of jboss, there's a service.bat that can install the service.

Comment: I use JBoss 4, so i don't think it is included in that version

Comment: I use JBoss 4.2.3.  There's a link on the page I linked to download the jboss native binaries for your platform.

Comment: Ah, found it now :)
I will try that now. Any tip how i can get set the jboss_out.log and the JBoss_err.log path, as i had in my main post :
"-out %PROJECT_HOME%\log\JBoss_out.log -err %PROJECT_HOME%\log\JBoss_err.log"

Comment: In service.bat, add redirection to the "call run.bat" line under cmdStart:, something like "call run.bat > out.log 2> err.log"

Comment: Thanks!
I'll try that tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks for great help. I still did not get the out.log and the err.log, but i guess the out.log is the same as the run.log now. But how about the err.log? Any idea on that one? Here is what i changed under the cmdStart:


call run.bat >out.log 2>err.log < .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1

Comment: If you run multi-instance with ports-01 configurations, etc.  , I see know way for this wrapper to load the "-Djboss.server.base.dir=..\ports-01" option when the service runs. This being the case, you must hard-code the option in standalone.conf.bat which precludes you from running multiple instances in the same directory.  Chicken or the egg.

Answer (score 2):

@karoberts answer is correct, although is different between version 4 and 5:

In JBoss 4:

```
{jboss.home}\bin\run.bat
```

In JBoss 5:

```
{jboss.home}\bin\run.conf.bat
```

Which one are you using?

The

```
service.bat
```

script of jboss native calls run.bat so you should put your JAVA_OPTS in there using the syntax

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dyoutoptionsgoeshere
```

Note: you won't find the service.bat in the bin anymore since JBoss 5. It's in a different package.

Comment: i'm using JBoss 4, and as i said in the second paragraph, i edited the run.bat and executed it, and it worked perfect. But when i installed it as a service, it would not work. I only get 64MB as max memory.

Comment: The service.bat file print the JAVA_OPTS in the run.log file. Would you mind posting your output?

Comment: Did not install it as a service in using service.bat, but i'm trying that tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

Another tip: 
If you have multiple Java Versions installed on your server and JBoss(4.2.3) service needs an older Version, you have to define the JAVA var in service.bat. If you use the run.bat also sometimes, then you need to define the JAVA var there too. 
I know that the service.bat calls the run.bat, but I tried just defining the JAVA var in the run.bat, when I then ran the service it ignored the new JAVA var content from run.bat

Here an example of how to set the JAVA var :

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6
set JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JavaService.exe as desribed above you can configure JVM options in the Windows Registry:

1.) Execute regedit.exe

2.) Goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CurrentControlSet\Services\JBoss\Parameters

3.) After initial installation you find a parameter "JVM Option Count" wich is set to 1 and "JVM Option Number 0" which basically contains a class path.

4.) Increase the value of "JVM Option Count" to 3

5.) Add a REG_SZ Parameter "JVM Option Number 1" and assign it the Value -Xms128m

6.) Add a REG_SZ Parameter "JVM Option Number 2" and assign it the Value -Xmx512m

Regards